# array formula is not working in google sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

**What I want to do:**

- Check if 4 of my cells are blank or not
- If all of them are not blank, then its okay, else display nothing ("")
- I want it to be auto dragged down

**What I have tried**

`=arrayformula(if(AND(not(A1:D=""),not(B1:B=""),not(C1:C=""),not(D1:D="")),"ok",""))`

**Result**

- Although the statements of AND is true, it displays nothing ""

What can be the issue in the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use `AND()` , `OR()` it won't work with array, I'm not sure why

But we can count `true/false` as a number of `1 = true` and `0 = false`

```
=arrayformula(if(not(A1:A="")+not(B1:B="")+not(C1:C="")+not(D1:D="")>3,"ok",))
```

Comment: That works! thanks. Solution is not to use the and or or in array. well noted!

Answer (score 0):

`AND` is not supported in AF.

use in row 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A1:A<>"")*(B1:B<>"")*(C1:C<>"")*(D1:D<>""); "ok"; ))
```

Comment: because i m dealing with numbers, it gives string error that the parameter expects numbered value

Comment: @player0 Comma-semicolon disorder strikes again. This logical expression is equivalent to another answer but looks simpler and should be used. Hey OP (@PythonDev) try changing `;` to `,` (function parameter delimiters) and it will work.

Comment: @PythonDev can you share a copy of your sheet?